# A subset of B and B subset of C implies A element of C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello I trie to understand why $A \subseteq B \subseteq C \to A \in C$ because it just implies $A \subseteq C$ or I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, $A \subseteq B \subseteq C \Rightarrow A \subseteq C$

Comment: It implies just $A\subset C$; i don't see any set that $A\subset C$ implies $A\in C$. Buuut, $A\in B\subset C$ does implies $A\in C$.

Comment: Ok thank you but it is related to that post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504991/is-union-of-two-matroids-a-matroid-itself , in the first answer 'But $A \cap X \subseteq A$, so $A \cap X \in S_1$' and the answer seems right.

Comment: @flow I know nothing about matroids, but it seems that they are closed under subsets i.e. $A\subset B$ and $B\in S$ implies $A\in S$. That's, maybe, a chacteristic of matroids, it does not holds in general.

Comment: Edgar is correct, that answer is talking about the independent sets $S_1$ of a matroid, which have the property that if $A\in S_1$ (meaning that $A$ is an independent set), then any subset $B$ of $A$ is also independent, so $B\subseteq A\in S_1\implies B\in S_1$. This is not a set theoretical statement.

Comment: Ahhhhh now I see it, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Still, your question is not well elaborated. It should say: $A\subset B \in C \to A\in C$. You should correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to test your guesses with simple examples.

Let A = B = C = Q, the set of rational numbers.
Thus, $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$. Clearly $A \subseteq C$.
How could A, the set of all rationals, 
be a single rational in Q = C?