# Subsets in the context of matroid independent sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matroids

[Is the disjoint union of two Matroids a Matroid itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504991/is-the-disjoint-union-of-two-matroids-a-matroid-itself)

> Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two disjoint sets. Moreover, assume that $(E_1,S_1)$ and $(E_2,S_2)$ are matroids.
>
> Define $S:=\{X \cup Y|X \subseteq S_1 \land Y \subseteq S_2\}$
>
> Prove that $(E_1 \cup E_2,S)$ is a matroid.

I am trying to understand the solution to the problem in the post above (note that matroids $(E,S)$ in this post are defined as a ground set $E$ and a set of independent sets $S$). I know how a matroid is defined and how to check whether a given tuple of sets $(E, S)$ is a matroid. What I don't understand is how I can guarantee that $\emptyset \in S$ since there is no restriction on which subsets $X, Y$ are taken from $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively.

As far as I understand, a subset relation $A \subseteq B$ puts no restriction on which elements of $B$ are in $A$ and $A = \emptyset$ also fulfills $A \subseteq B$. Thus, I don't know how to guarantee that $\emptyset \in S$, which is a requirement for $(E,S)$ to be a matroid according to the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets). Therefore, to my knowledge, $(E,S)$ is not a matroid, contrary to the answer to the post above.

I would be really thankful if you could help me to understand where my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: But $\emptyset \in S_1$ and $\emptyset \in S_2$. Thus $\emptyset=\emptyset \cup \emptyset \in S$.

Comment: This looks a bit strange. Shouldn't it be $X \in S_1 \wedge Y \in S_2$? Otherwise elements of $S$ are not subsets of $E$, but rather subsets of $\mathcal P(E)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But isn't $S$ defined in terms of $X$ and $Y$? Sure, if $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ it is clear that $\emptyset \in S$ - but in this case, $\emptyset \in X \lor \emptyset \in Y$ would have to hold, right?

Comment: @mihaild I don't think so, since $S$ is a *set of independent sets*, which would not make sense if $X$ and $Y$ do not contain sets.

Comment: Let's say that for example $E_1 = \{1, 2\}$, $S_1$ contain, in particular, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. Then we can take $X = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ and have $\{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ as independent set, which makes no sense as independent set should be subset of $E$.

Comment: @mihaild I see your point, thanks for giving an example! I also think I understand the task better now...